# Azure Data Factory DataFlow md5 specific columns

Tags: azure-data-factory

First of all, I have my array of columns parameter called $array_merge_keys

```
$array_merge_keys = ['Column1', 'Column2', 'NoColumnInSomeCases']
```

So then I am going to hash them, if the third `NoColumnInSomeCases` is not existed, I would like to treat it as null or some strings else there value.

But actually, when I use them with `byNames()`, it would return NULL because the last is not existed, even though first and second still have values. So I would expect byNames($array_merge_keys) always return value in order to hash them.

Since that problem cannot be solved, I am back to filter these only existed column

```
filter(columnNames('', true()), contains(['Column1', 'Column2', 'NoColumnInSomeCases'], #item_1 == #item)) => ['Column1', 'Column2']
```

But it comes to another problem that `byNames()` cannot compute on the fly, it said `'byNames' does not accept column or argument`

```
array(byNames(filter(columnNames('', true()), contains(['Column1', 'Column2', 'NoColumnInSomeCases'], #item_1 == #item))))
```

> Spark job failed: { "text/plain":
> "{"runId":"649f28bf-35af-4472-a170-1b6ece50c551","sessionId":"a26089f4-b0f4-4d24-8b79-d2a91a9c52af","status":"Failed","payload":{"statusCode":400,"shortMessage":"DF-EXPR-030
> at Derive 'CreateTypeFromFile'(Line 35/Col 36): Column name function
> 'byNames' does not accept column or argument
> parameters","detailedMessage":"Failure 2022-04-13 05:26:31.317
> failed DebugManager.processJob,
> run=649f28bf-35af-4472-a170-1b6ece50c551, errorMessage=DF-EXPR-030 at
> Derive 'CreateTypeFromFile'(Line 35/Col 36): Column name function
> 'byNames' does not accept column or argument parameters"}}\n" } -
> RunId: 649f28bf-35af-4472-a170-1b6ece50c551

I have tried lots of ways, even created a new derived column (before that stream name) to store ['Column1', 'Column2']. But it said that `column cannot be referenced within byNames() function`

Do we have any elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that byName() cannot evaluate with late binding. You need to either use a Select transformation to set the columns in the stream you wish to hash first or send in the column names via a parameter. Since that is "early column binding", byName() will work.

You can use a get metadata activity in the pipeline to inspect which columns are present in your source before calling the data flow, allowing you to send a pipeline parameter with just those columns you wish to hash.

Alternatively, you can create a new branch, use a select matching rule, then hash the row based on those columns (see example below).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Select which columns are the way that I have tested after 8 hours of discovery. First, I will create the Incremental Key, then select columns to hash, after that I am going to join them again with Incremental Key and back to my stream.